# Fitch System For logic proofs

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, formal-proofs

Does anyone know the Fitch program/ system used for logical proofs ?

I am stuck with using fitch to construct a proof of¬(¬A∨¬B) from the premises A and B       ... This is how it looks like in fitch https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mn55.png and this is what I have done so far https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQlpN.png

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  From experience, I can tell you that you will have a much better chance of getting feedback if you present us with a specific problem you are having, and show us where *you* get stuck.  As it currently is, your question is far too general, and this community also would really like to see that you have put some effort and thought into whatever problem you are dealing with. ... but yes, there are people here who know Fitch ...

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited my question. Thank you again

Comment: OK, that's better .. but now we still would like to see what you tried.  Also, please try using the MathJax typesetting format. Here is a quick [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: hmmm, looks like you didn't try anything ... you don't have any thoughts about this one at all?

Comment: I attached what I have tried. This is not my only trial. I have tried more than ten times but non worked

Comment: OK, this is a good try!  Yes, proof by contradiction, and then a proof by cases! Remember that the $\lor$ Elim rule infers the statement that is at the end of each of the subproofs ... what statement is that?

Comment: thank you soo much for being helpful. I really really really appreciate it

Comment: I tried using V Elim rule but it did not work

Comment: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Like I said, the $\lor$ Elim rule wants to see the same statement after the subproofs as the statements at the end of each of the subproofs ... again, what statement is at the end of each subproof?

Comment: should the statement be the original goal?                                                            the statement at the end of each of my subproofs is ⊥

Comment: No, it is not the original goal ... it is the *new* goal which, since you are doing a proof by contradiction, should be $\bot$ ... and lo and behold, that's exactly what you have at the end of each subproof!

Comment: Ok,  I think I got what you are saying

Comment: I am sorry I am so confused

Comment: I got them all right now! Thank you sooooo much

Comment: Don't apologize ... you are not as confused as you think, and are actually really close! ... See?!

Comment: Your comments are such a great help. God bless you

Comment: My pleasure ... I'll post some tips in my Answer in a second...

Comment: Oh, thank you. the steps really make sense to me now

Comment: OK, I posted the general 'thought process' for this proof ... try and do that for other proofs as well!

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaank you so much. Life is muuuch easier now

Comment: Glad I could help ... but don't get excited too quickly ... these proofs are hard to get your head around in the beginning. It'll take a while before you'll be proficient. Practice is key ... but always keep calm and think of the proof set-up. And like I said, you did well already: proof by cases within a proof by contradiction is exactly what you needed to be doing for this one. Good job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing Fitch proofs, *set-up* is key!!

OK, so your goal is $\neg (\neg A \lor \neg B)$ ... which is a negation ... which suggests a proof by Contradiction, i.e $\neg$ Intro.  Now, here is the all-important point: when setting up the proof by contradiction, make sure to enter the $\bot$ at the end of the subproofs, and to apply the $\neg$ Intro rule before doing anything else! That is, do:

[image]

Notice how you can already check out the $\neg$ Intro rule!

OK, so now you have $\neg A \lor \neg B$ to work with, which is a disjunction, so that suggests setting up a proof by cases, i.e. $\lor$ Elim:

[image]

Again, though, make sure that at the end of each subproof you put the statement that is going to be your goal before doing anything else. OK, but what is the goal? Well, since you're within the subproof of the proof by contradiction, that goal is $\bot$. So:

[image]

Again, notice how you can already check the correct application of the $\lor$ Elim rule.

OK, so this is what's called the *proof skeleton* (or proof plan, or proof strategy, or proof overview, or proof organization, or ... ).  This gives you the basic organization of the proof.  The rest is details ... and as you found out yourself, the rest is in fact completely trivial!

Good luck with future Fitch proofs!

Comment: This explanation is sooo perfect!

Comment: An excellent "how to" lesson rather than "here's the answer".  Very nicely done.  $\checkmark$

Comment: I agree! That is better than the lectures. I wish my instructor gave us clear explanation for lessons like this.