# Proof in Fitch and counterexample in Tarski's World

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Good official afternoon community,

I am trying to prove (P → Q) ↔ (¬Q →¬P)  without premises. I do not understand why it is not working, I need to study such exercises to be able to pass the final. Please help me. I do not want just an answer I want someone to explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it because that will help me understand the concept.

Would you please help me, I appreciate your time

mark

Comment: You have proved $P \to Q \vdash \lnot Q \to \lnot P$ and thus you have $(P \to Q) \to (\lnot Q \to \lnot P)$.

Comment: Now you have to "reverse" teh implication, proving $(\lnot Q \to \lnot P) \to (P \to Q)$.

Comment: With the two results, you can conclude with the bi-conditional: $\leftrightarrow$.

Comment: I will try this now

Comment: is the FO con correct or do I need to change the rule

Comment: I think not... You have to sart a new sub-proof from $(\lnot Q \to \lnot P)$ and assuming $\lnot Q$ and $\lnot P$ and use the contradiction to derive $\lnot \lnot P$. Then use double negation and conclude. After that, "add" the two sub-proof with $\leftrightarrow$-intro,

Comment: I do not know why it is not working with me. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me, I appreciate it. I will try to go over the chapter again and try to understand.

Comment: Isn't this exercise 8.17? This link might help https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/37405/fitch-proof-lpl-exercise-8-17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fitch is not accepting your 'proof' because it really is not a proof, and that's because you rely on FO Con, which is not a formal inference rule, but rather a clever mechanism that is able to check whether some statement validly follows from some others or not .  Hey, if you would be allowed to use FO Con, you could just do:

[image]

... but clearly that shouldn't count as a proof!

OK,  *set-up* and *organization* are key to completing these formal proofs, and subproofs are the key to providing that organization. Take a look here for [how to create the set-up for Fitch Proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2463732/fitch-system-for-logic-proofs/2463751#2463751), and here for [how to deal with subproofs in Fitch](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467255/formally-prove-that-these-two-premises-are-contradictory/2467442#2467442)

OK, for your specific problem, you need to derive $P \rightarrow Q$ from $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$.  Since your goal is a $\rightarrow$, the thing to do is to use a Conditional Proof, i.e to set up a $\rightarrow$ Intro:

[image]

OK, so now you need to prove $Q$, which is an atomic statement. On strategy for trying to prove atomic statements is to do a Proof by Contradiction, i.e. assume the negation of that atomic statement, and show that leads to a contradiction. So, that would suggest the following proof skeleton:

[image]

OK, from here it should not be very hard ...

Comment: I edited the question and attached what I did for the second subproof in the question because two steps are not checking. I do not know why they are not though

Comment: @markjohn OK, line 12 does not follow from line 9.  You are basically trying to infer $B$ from $A \rightarrow B$ ... well, does that make sense?  Think about this: "If I win the loittery, then I am happy. Therefore, I am happy" ... clearly I can't make that kind of inference! You can't just get rid of a condition. Indeed, the only way to eliminate a $\rightarrow$ is if you have the very condition ('if' part) as another given.

Comment: @markjohn More importantly, though, on line 15 you are trying to infer $P\rightarrow Q$ from lines 10-14?!? First of all, those lines comprise three subporofs, and the $\rightarrow$ Intro requires exactly one subproof. Second, thre assumptoin of the required subproof is $P$, and the last line should be $Q$ ... you have that just the other way around. So, no, this is not at all a valid inference.  Remember organization and set-up is everything! Make sure you know *why* you start a subproof and what you do with it. Take another look at my answer for a good set-up for this second subproof.

Comment: OK, thank you, I will try this now. You are such a great teacher

Comment: @markjohn OK, good luck!  Also, at the bottom of mt Answer I added a link to another post of mine that specifically talks about subproofs.

Comment: Thank you, I am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: The thing is, it is not making sense to me. I went to the professor and she said that I should know those things by now. I might have logical developmental delays. hah

Comment: I will read the link now, thank you

Comment: @markjohn  Yeah, ok, that's not going to work ... you are in the middle of trying to prove $P \rightarrow Q$, so don't expect that you should be able to prove $P \rightarrow Q$ in the middle of that.  OK, so did your teacher give you a set of strategies for proving various kinds of statements?  In particular: your goal is $Q$, which is an atomic statement ... one strategy might be to prove that by a proof by Contradiction:  Assume $\neg Q$, and see if that leads to a contradiction ...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwbzq.png.... I do not think I can do more than that. The thing is, it is making more sense to me now as I read the explanation, but I am still unsure about the rules. I now know why logic and math people are so intelligent, I really cannot handle math.

Comment: @markjohn Do *not* give up!  You're close!!!  OK, the $\lor$ Elim does not work since you do not have any $\lor$ to work with .... However, after assuming $\neg Q$, what can you infer given whatever else you have?

Comment: @markjohn No need to apologize! I'm here to help.  OK, the problem with what you have now is that you try to close two subproofs at once, and you are not allowed to do that.  You need to close subproof one at a time.  Also, you no longer follow thew original set-up of assuming $P$ and getting to $Q$ in the outside subproof, so put that back in. OK, I'll add another HINT to my Answer

Comment: I will do one that follows the original set-up. Thank you

Comment: At least I understand what I am doing now.

Comment: @markjohn OK, I added to my post. Good luck!

Comment: @markjohn Too bad you didn't have a good experience ... but I wish you the best as well!